# Meteor Dropdown Menu Not Working In Mobile View

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been following the DiscoverMeteor tutorial starter edition and all is working well apart from the dropdown menu not working when the browser window is narrowed to show the 3-bar button. There is no response when clicking this button.

My installed packages are as follows:

- accounts-password            1.0.4  Password support for accounts
- ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  1.1.22* Bootstrap-styled accounts-ui with multi-language support.
- iron:router                  1.0.1 Routing specifically designed for Meteor
- meteor-platform              1.2.0  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
- mizzao:bootstrap-3           3.3.0  HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first ...
- sacha:spin                   2.0.4  Simple spinner package for Meteor
- underscore                   1.0.1  Collection of small helpers: _.map, _.each, ...

I am using Chrome version 38.0.2125.122.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm. My drop down is working now but I have not changed any packages or settings. The only thing I can think of is that in "prettifying" some of the code layout, I may have fixed an obscure issue arising from copying and pasting the code from the book and it breaking oddly across lines.